# get minimum record in query mysql

Tags: mysql, sql, join, left-join

Hi Folks I am new to queries and dnt have much idea how can we achieve this

I have two tables products and customproducts. Custom product hv productid and count number.

```
id :  pid :  count : belong 
1      200      5 .   1
2      201      2     1
3      203      0 .   1
4      204      6 .   2
```

Product table have product information like id name description and so on

I am trying to make a query to get all product they hv belong and least count number must be greater thn zero.

in this I want product id 201 as result.

I am trying below querie

```
Select *
from product as e inner join
    `customproducts` AS `u`
     on u.product_id = e.id
```

but here i am getting only product hv record in customproducts table

Comment: You've only showed data for one of the tables, and I'm not sure we can answer with certainty without seeing data from the other table.  Unclear what you are asking.

Answer (score 0):

Try this with where cluase:

```
Select *
from product as e inner join
    `customproducts` AS `u`
     on u.product_id = e.id where count>0
```

Comment: but they should b from same belong id how can I implemet that

Comment: do you've belong id in both table

Answer (score 0):

You could use a join  with  a subquery for  min count  > 0

```
Select *
from product as e 
inner join customproducts AS u  on u.product_id = e.id
inner join (
  select  min(count)  from customproducts min_count
  where count > 0
)  t on t.min_count  = u.count
```

and for the same belong id

```
Select *
from product as e 
inner join customproducts AS u  on u.product_id = e.id
inner join (
  select belong, min(count) min_count from customproducts 
  where count > 0
  group by belong
)  t on t.min_count  = u.count and t.belong= u.belong
```

Comment: but they should b from same belong id how can I implement that

Comment: can you please tell mw what is min_count?

Comment: i am getting Unknown column 't.min_count' in 'on clause'

Comment: @Daniel_12  ... answer updated .. wrong position for alias